# What does Alternate NA mean on an approach plate?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, usa

The `ILS Y or LOC Y RWY 3` approach at Raleigh Exec Jetport at Sanford-Lee County Airport (KTTA) in Sanford, North Carolina features the alternate minimums symbol with an `NA` next to it. Normally this symbol means that the airport has non-standard alternate minimums. What does `A NA` mean in this case?

[image: Alternate N/A]

Comment: Another example is [ILS or LOC RWY 33](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1607/05677il33.pdf) into KFNL. DPE Andy Munnis uses this approach to illustrate an approach not being authorized for an alternate in his talk about [commonly missed items on the instrument oral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUzR8f1Npss#t=54m17s), beginning around 54:17.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That symbology means this approach cannot be considered when deciding if this airport is a suitable alternate.  This is probably due to the lack of weather reporting or the navaid might not have the required monitoring.  This means the availability of the approach cannot be guaranteed and so you can not rely on it as an alternate.

To file TTA as an alternate you must comply with the the non-standard alternate minimums and you must be legal and equipped to fly either the RNAV (GPS) RWY 03 or RNAV (GPS) RWY 21 procedures.  If the ILS Y RWY 03 is available when you get there, you may fly that procedure instead of the RNAV procedures, you just cannot file it as an alternate on the basis of the ILS.

The wording in the [Terminal Procedures legend (PDF)](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1512/frntmatter.pdf) is

> Alternate minimums are Not Authorized due to unmonitored facility or absence of weather reporting service

Comment: Ye link breaketh.